# Remove Entry Text at first click

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a entry/Textbox. And i have 10 number buttons as a calculator.(0-1-2-3-4....) When my page loaded entry having a number. Its showing me start value.( For example when my page loaded entry text being 10 already without any click to button) So i want to when i click a number button It will delete first entry value that loaded with page and it will start write my button clicks. How can I do it ?

I tried with:

```
private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
entry.Text="";
entry.Text="1";
```

But of course it didn't work because if i want to write 123 I cant write its always deleting. I just want delete first value which is coming with page loaded.

Comment: why not use the Placeholder property to display the start value?  Otherwise you will need to use a bool to track if this is the first button click or not

Answer (score 0):

As @Jason suggested use the [Placeholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#set-placeholder-text) property to display the initial value and in the click events append the value to the entry text:

Note: you can have a single event delegate that handle the click event for all buttons:

```
Constructor()
{
     //set initial value here or use binding
     //entry.Placeholder = 
}

private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //you can remove the initial value if you want
    //entry.Placeholder = string.Empty;
    
    string buttonText = ((Button)sender).Text;
    entry.Text = $"{entry.Text}{buttonText}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to add a boolean flag out of the method to avoid this.

```
public class MyCalculator ()
{
    private bool _isNewNumber;

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        _isNewNumber = true; //whenever open the page, needs to refresh
    }

    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isNewNumber)
        {
            entry.Text=""; //clear the number for the first time
        }

        entry.Text="1";
        _isNewNumber = false;
    }
}
```